# How to enable browser-specific color picker for a color input in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Both Chrome and Firefox provide a beautiful color picker in dev tools. But every time I click a `<input type="color" />`, a xp-like color dialog jumps out. Most importantly, I cannot select opacity in Windows color picker.

Edit:
I want to use color picker in dev tools.
[image]

as opposed to this one:
[image]
<sub>(source: [softpedia-static.com](http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/Steinberger-Easy-Color-Picker_2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Check [Spectrum Color Picker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/). Its easy to use and moreover you have quite the power to customize the color picker by various options including the opacity.

```
$("#showAlpha").spectrum({
    showAlpha: true
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand on your question but i think it will helpful for you 
[it will help you](http://cssdeck.com/labs)